# How do I rewrite this code for V8 from Rhino?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, v8, rhino

I used to a script on GAS.
Because I do manage attendance by Chat and Google spread sheet with GAS.
Chat tool is Chat work.
It works on Gas(Rhino).
But It doesn't work V8.

I tried to rewrite line19 `for each (var obj in json){` to `for (var obj in json){`

Please tell me what is bad...
Which should I rewrite it?

```
function recordTime(){
  /*Sheet setting*/
  var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("data"); //DataSheetSetting
  var wsStaff = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("coworkers"); //CoworkersMasterSetting
  /*ChatworkURLrequest*/
  var params = {
    headers : {"X-ChatWorkToken" : 'anynumber'},
    method : "get"
  };
  var roomID = anynumber; //ROOMID
  var url = "https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/" + roomID + "/messages?force=0"; //GetMessageFromGroupchat
  try{
    var respons = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params); //GetResponseFromChatworkAPIendpoint
    var json = JSON.parse(respons.getContentText()); //Returnjson
    for each(var obj in json){　//I understand that I should rewrite "for (var obj in json){
      /*Get YMDhm and ID*/      
      var date = new Date(obj.send_time*1000); 
      var date_D = new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate(),0,0,0); 
      var date_T = new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate(),date.getHours(),date.getMinutes(),0); 　
      var date_TH = new Date(0,0,0,date.getHours(),date.getMinutes(),0); 　
      /*dateToSn Setting*/      
      var MILLIS_DIFFERENCE = 9 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 
      var COEFFICIENT = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 
      var DATES_OFFSET = 70 * 365 + 17 + 1 + 1; 
      function dateToSn(date){ //Date→Serial
        return convertUt2Sn(date.getTime());
      }
      function convertUt2Sn(unixTimeMillis){ //UNIX→Serial
        return (unixTimeMillis + MILLIS_DIFFERENCE) / COEFFICIENT + DATES_OFFSET;
      }
      /*findRow*/      
      function findRow(sheet,val,col){
        var dat = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
        for(var i=1;i<dat.length;i++){
          if(dat[i][col-1] === val){
            return i+1;
          }
        }
        return 0;
      }
      /*StaffID*/
      var staffID = wsStaff.getRange(findRow(wsStaff,obj.account.account_id,1),2).getValue(); 
      var dataRow=findRow(wsData,dateToSn(date_D)+staffID.toString(),1);      
      if(obj.body.match(/出勤/)){ 
        if(!dataRow){
          wsData.appendRow(
            ["=INDIRECT(\"RC[1]\",FALSE) & INDIRECT(\"RC[2]\",FALSE)",date_D,
             "=VLOOKUP(" + obj.account.account_id + ",'coworkers'!A:B,2,FALSE)","=VLOOKUP(" + obj.account.account_id + ",'coworkers'!A:E,4,FALSE)","出勤",date_T
            ]);    
        }
      }else if(obj.body.match(/外出/) || obj.body.match(/直行/)){
        if(dataRow){
          var rng = wsData.getRange(dataRow,8);
          if(!rng.getValue()){
            rng.setValue(date_T);
          }
        }
      }else if(obj.body.match(/帰社/) || obj.body.match(/直帰/)){
        if(dataRow){
          var rng = wsData.getRange(dataRow,9);
          if(!rng.getValue()){
            rng.setValue(date_T);
          }
        }
      }else if (obj.body.match(/中抜け/)){
        if(dataRow){
          var rng = wsData.getRange(dataRow,10);
          if(!rng.getValue()){
            rng.setValue(date_T);
          }
        }
      }else if (obj.body.match(/戻り/)){
        if(dataRow){
          var rng = wsData.getRange(dataRow,11);
          if(!rng.getValue()){
            rng.setValue(date_T);
          }
        }
      }else if(obj.body.match(/退勤/)){
        if(dataRow){
          var rng = wsData.getRange(dataRow,7);
          if(!rng.getValue()){
            rng.setValue(date_T);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }catch(e){
    Logger.log('Error');
    Logger.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the official documention here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#avoid_for_eachvariable_in_object

In short:

```
for each (var obj in json) {
  do_something_with(obj);
}
```

becomes

```
for (var obj of json) {
  do_something_with(obj);
}
```

Note that `in` changed to `of`, which makes the `for`-loop iterate over values rather than keys. Accordingly, you can also use a traditional `for-in` loop, and manually use the key to get the value:

```
for (var obj_key in json) {
  var obj = json[obj_key];
  do_something_with(obj);
}
```

You can also use `let` instead of `var` to get block-scoped variables, which are generally more intuitive to use, but that's an unrelated change and is not required if you just want things to work.

Comment: I tried change in to of.
It is worked!
Thanks a lot.
And I will try manually use the key to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Google apps script switched runtime engines from Rhino to V8. This caught me by surprise too and borked a bunch of my code, including date and year manipulation.

Years are handled differently. getYear() no longer works as expected.

You can switch back to the old Rhino. See [Enabling the Rhino Runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_rhino_runtime)

There is info about V8 available at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime

Google has published a list of [incompatibilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#incompatibilities) and [other differences](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#other_differences) which contains good documentation about work arounds.

Full link for script migration: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration

Fortunately it's not the drama I was expecting. It would have been nice to have been given a heads up beforehand though.